# GUI question : representing large tree

Tags: gui

I have a tree-like datastructure of some six levels deep, that I would like to represent on a single webpage (can be tabs, trees; ....)

In each level both childnodes and content are possible.  Presenting it like a real tree would be not very usable (too big).

I was thinking in the lines of hiding parts of the tree when you drill down and presenting a breadcrumbs or the like to keep you informed as to where you are...

I guess my question boils down to  : any ideas / examples ?

Tx!

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the way [Visual Thesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/) handles its complex tree structures?  With their visualization, they can easily handle more than six levels in a tree.

Comment: +1, tx, it might be an idea, but they don't do 6 levels of course, and what's more, it only works if the content is rather small

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the JIT spacetree visualisation (www.thejit.org). They use JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to consider an approach like [github's tree slider,](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider) which allows you to drill down through complex directory and file structures.

It's a beautiful solution to display complex datasets, and their implementation is the best I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Freemind is a Mindmap creator that exports to flash and to html with JavaScript. It's very easy to use and efficient, but the looks is not as spectacular as the solutions above.